# Как выбрать строку файле и вывести скрипт

Tags: python

```
baze = open('../baze.txt', 'r+') #чтение базы
Выбрать строку в файле 1.py = 40
import sys
sys.stdout=open('1.py','w') #запись базы в программу
for line in (baze) (со строки 40):
    print('try:')
    print('123' + line.strip() +')
```

Попробуйте этот скрипт он работает правильно, но мне нужно что бы просто весь результат был в 40-ой строке файла 1.py

Comment: Резултать должен быть такой из файла первого переносится   текст и добавляется ещё текст который снизу всё это во второй файл в 40 строку

Comment: Тут рабочий скрипт просто не знаю как что бы во второй файл записалось с 40 строки,  сам файл второй уже содержит то что нужно

Comment: Помоги пожалуйста, Андрей)

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Ну если второй файл уже содержит то, что нужно и надо писать дальше, укажите режим append:

```
with open("1.py", "a") as file:
    file.write("try:")
    # и так далее
```